# Scale image object to match another object's scale

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I have two sets of images of different size for each set. The first set is images of 400x400 pixels with real picture objects.

[image]

The second set is 319x319, with image silhouettes of different scale than the real picture objects.

[image]

What I want to achieve, is basically to have the silhouettes replaced by the real picture objects (i.e. beaver) of the first set. So the end result will be 319x319 resolution images with real picture objects. Here is an example:

[image: example of the desired result]

The first set images cannot simply be resized to 319x319, since the beaver will not match the silhouette. There are about 100 images with different "***beaver size*** to ***beaver's silhouette size***" relationships. Is there a way to automate this procedure?

So far, I've tried @cxw suggestion up to step 2. Here is the code of [EllipseDirectFit](http://pastebin.com/VGkniMbE) I used. And here is my [code](http://pastebin.com/F7j0N5Dp) to plot the images with the ellipse fits. I don't know how to proceed to steps 3-5.. I think from EllipseDirectFit function -> 2*abs(A(1)) should be the ellipsi's major axes. (NOTE: 'a1.bmp' is the real image and 'b1.bmp' is the silhouette).

Comment: Do you always have flat-color backgrounds like you showed in the question outside of the real image or silhouette?

Comment: yes always flat-color backgrounds for both real images and silhouettes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have code for this, but here's how I would proceed, just off-hand.  There's almost certainly a better way :) .

1. For each of the real image and the silhouette image:

   1. Get the X, Y coordinates of the pixels that *aren't* the background.  **Edit** Example tested in Octave:

      ```
      background_R = img(1,1,1)
      background_G = img(1,1,2)
      background_B = img(1,1,3)

      [xs,ys]=find(img(:,:,1)~=background_R | img(:,:,2)~=background_G | img(:,:,3)~=background_B)
      ```

      The logical OR is because the image can differ from the background in any color component.
   2. Fit an ellipse to the X, Y coordinate pairs you found.  E.g., use [this routine](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22684-ellipse-fit--direct-method-) from File Exchange.  (Actually, I suppose you could use a circle fit or any other shape fit you wanted, as long as size and position are the only differences between the non-background portions of the images.)
2. Now you have ellipse parameters for the real image and the silhouette image.  Assuming the aspect ratios are the same, those ellipses should differ only in center and scale.
3. Resize the real image ([`imresize`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imresize.html)) based on the ratio of silhouette ellipse major axis length to real image ellipse major axis length.  Now they should be the same size.
4. Find the centers.  Using the above fit routine,

   ```
   A=EllipseDirectFit(...)
   % switch to Mathworld notation from http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Ellipse.html
   ma=A(1); mb=A(2)/2; mc=A(3); md=A(4)/2; mf=A(5)/2; mg=A(6);
   center_x = (mc*md-mb*mf)/(mb**2-ma*mc)
   center_y = (ma*mf-mb*md)/(mb**2-ma*mc)
   ```
5. Move the real image data in a 3-d matrix so that the ellipse centers 
   coincide.  For example,

   ```
   cx_silhouette = ... (as above, for the silhouette image)
   cy_silhouette = ...
   cx_real = ... (as above, for the *resized* real image)
   cy_real = ...
   shifted = zeros(size(silhouette_image)) % where we're going to put the real image
   deltax = cx_silhouette - cx_real
   deltay = cy_silhouette - cy_real
   % if deltax==deltay==0, you're done with this step.  If not:
   portion = resized_real_image(max(deltay,0):319-abs(deltay), max(deltax,0):319-abs(deltax), :);  % or something like that - grab the overlapping part of the resized real image
   shifted(max(deltay,0):min(deltay+319,319), max(deltax,0):min(deltax+319,319), :) = portion; % or something like that - slide the portion of the resized real image in x and y.  Now _shifted_ should line up with the silhouette image.
   ```
6. Using the background color (or the black silhouette — same difference) as a mask, copy pixels from the resized, moved real image into the silhouette image.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried fitting an ellipse or a circle, but they always capture an inner part of the image (even for the silhouette which flat-colored inside).. :/

Comment: Sure, that makes sense.  The question is whether they capture the _same_ inner part of the image.  Since the fitting only involves the X and Y values, not the pixel values, the ellipses you get should cover the same part of the outline (and not necessarily the whole thing) regardless of the size of the image or which image.  Does that make sense?  I'd be happy to look further --- if you wish, please update the question to include your code up to this point and some screenshots of the fit ellipses superimposed on the images.

Comment: Here is the code of [EllipseDirectFit](http://pastebin.com/VGkniMbE) I used. And here is my [code](http://pastebin.com/F7j0N5Dp) to plot the images with the ellipse fits. I don't know how to proceed to your steps 3-5.. I think from EllipseDirectFit function -> 2*abs(A(1)) should be the ellipsi's major axes. Is that correct? btw, a1.bmp is the real image and b1.bmp is the silhouette just like my original post.

Comment: Updated the xs/ys selection with actual tested code fragment :) based on yours.

Comment: hmmm...but, this I had already implemented..How does it help?

Comment: Ok, I see that the use of OR is more correct.. Now in step 3, I managed to resize the image based on the suggested ratio and now they are of the same size. Can you extrapolate a bit on steps 4 and 5?

Comment: Edited - still not tested :/

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone else has the same problem as me, I post the code that solved my problem. I actually followed [cxw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2877364/cxw)'s suggestion and fitted an ellipse for both real and silhouette pictures, then resized the real picture based on the ratio of the silhouette-ellipse's major axis to the real-ellipse major axis. This made the image object match in size the silhouette image object (i.e. the beaver). Then I either cropped, or added border pixels to match the resolution I needed (i.e. 319x319).

```
% fetching the images
realList = getAllFiles('./real_images'); % getAllFiles => StackOverflow function
silhList = getAllFiles('./silhouettes');

for qq = 1:numel(realList)
    % Name of the file to save
    str = realList{qq}(15:end);

    a = imread(realList{qq});   % assign real image
    background_Ra = a(1,1,1);   % getting the background colors
    background_Ga = a(1,1,2);
    background_Ba = a(1,1,3);
    % finding the points (x,y) to pass to fit_ellipse
    [x1,y1]=find(a(:,:,1)~=background_Ra | a(:,:,2)~=background_Ga | a(:,:,3)~=background_Ba);
    % fitting an ellipse to these points
    z1 = fit_ellipse(x1,y1); % Mathworks file exchange function

    b = imread(silhList{qq});   % assign silhouette image
    background_R2b = b(1,1,1);  % getting the background colors
    background_G2b = b(1,1,2);
    background_B2b = b(1,1,3);
    % finding the points (x,y) to pass to fit_ellipse
    [x2,y2]=find(b(:,:,1)~=background_R2b & b(:,:,2)~=background_G2b & b(:,:,3)~=background_B2b);
    % fitting an ellipse to these points
    z2 = fit_ellipse(x2,y2);

    % ratio of silhouette's ellipse major axis to real image's ellipse
    % major axis
    ellaxratio = z2.long_axis/z1.long_axis;
    % resizing based on ellaxratio, so that the real image object size will
    % now fit the silhouette's image object size
    c = imresize(a,ellaxratio); c = rgb2gray(c);
    bordercolor = c(end,end); 

    % if the resulting image is smaller, add pixels around it until they
    % match with the silhouette image resolution
    if size(c) < 319
        while size(c) < 319
            % 'addborder' is a Mathworks file exchange function
            c = addborder(c(:,:,1),1, bordercolor ,'outer'); 
        end
    % if the resulting image is larger, crop pixels until they match
    else size(c) > 319
        while size(c) > 319
            c = c(2:end-1,2:end-1);
        end
    end

    % in a few cases, the resulting resolution is 318x318, instead of
    % 319x319, so a small adjustment won't hurt.
    if size(c) ~= 319
        c = imresize(c,[319 319]);
    end
    % saving..
    imwrite(c,['./good_fits/' str '.bmp'])
end
```